# MySQL Error 1005 on Create Table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1005

I was creating a new database on MySQL Workbench, but I get a lot of errors. So I tried create manually. But I get another error too, I can't understand what is happening.

That's my SQL code:

```
CREATE DATABASE data;

USE data;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TB_CHILD` (
 `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `NAME` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
 `STATUS` ENUM('A','I') NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TB_PARENT` (
 `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `TITLE` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
 `CHILD` INT NOT NULL ,
 `STATUS` ENUM('A','I') NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
 INDEX `FK_PARENT_CHILD` (`CHILD` ASC) ,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_PARENT_CHILD`
   FOREIGN KEY (`CHILD` )
   REFERENCES `TB_CHILD` (`ID` ))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I always get the error code 1005. I'm using Mysql Server 5.5. What's wrong with my code?

EDIT: Updated with the code USE data; But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you a trying to create an index to a field that doesn't exist yet:

```
INDEX `FK_PARENT_CHILD` (`CHILD` ASC) ,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_PARENT_CHILD`
   FOREIGN KEY (`CHILD` )
   REFERENCES `TB_CHILD` (`ID` ))
```

try to revert the order:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_PARENT_CHILD`
   FOREIGN KEY (`CHILD` )
   REFERENCES `TB_CHILD` (`ID` )),
INDEX `FK_PARENT_CHILD` (`CHILD` ASC)
```

Comment: That'it, but I'm still getting errors when I'm tried to Set values on the Parent table... but that first problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: This is not an error reason. You even may not create this index, it will be created by INNODB automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Use the created data base "data".

```
use data;
```

Your database needs to be created only once, but you must select it for use each time you begin a mysql session.if you did not selected the data base , the table creation fails. So that you are getting the error 1005.

Answer (score 1):

you created the database but you didn't select it to create the tables, try:

```
CREATE DATABASE data;

use data;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TB_CHILD` (
...
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the problem. If you execute the code, only the table Parent can't be created. The problem is on the FK. But I don't know what.